# Get row and column index of named cell

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, row, col

I tried to solve small problem with HTML table. I have a table where each TD has its unique name. I tried to get row and column index of so named cells but I was successful only with cellIndex,

```
var rownr=document.getElementById("cell122").cellIndex;
```

where cell122 is ID of the correspondent TD, but rowIndex returned "undefined" value. 
Is it possible?

Comment: I'd assume `#cell122` is not `TD` ...? Or your ids are not unique. Wait! `TD`s don't have `rowIndex`, only `TR`s have. You've to get `rowIndex` from `parentNode` of `TD`.

Comment: I have a PHP routine that generate unique ID for each TD of the table. I thought that I should be able to get to which tow and column of the table belongs clicked TD. Thanks for your opinion.

Comment: "`TD`s don't have `rowIndex`, only `TR`s have" is not an opinion, it's a fact. You can get `rowIndex` of a row containing the clicked cell by checking cell's `.parentElement.rowIndex` or `.parentNode.rowIndex`.

Answer (score 0):

For rowIndex use the tr:

https://jsfiddle.net/co8pxq2f/1/

```
   var row = document.querySelectorAll("table#test tr");
   for (var i = 0; i < row.length;i++) {
       row[i].textContent = "RowIndex is "+ row[i].rowIndex;
   }
```